# Is it possible to get the CPU Utilization of AWS Lambda in Percentage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

Is it possible to get the CPU utilization of AWS Lambda in Percentage ? Lambda Insights provides the CPU metrics in milliseconds. For a fair comparison between AWS ECS and Lambda, I am looking to get the Lambda CPU utilization percent.. Is it possible to convert ?

Comment: May be of interest: [lambdash](https://alestic.com/2014/11/aws-lambda-environment/).